# Sufficient conditions for constant solutions

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

Let $u : \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth **negative** function that satisfies
$$-f(x)u(x) + B(x) = \Delta u(x),~\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^N,$$
where $B(x)$ is a smooth positive function and $f$ is a smooth function with at least one zero. In particular, one can decompose $\mathbb{R}^N = \Omega\cup \Omega'$, where $f\Big|_{\Omega} > 0$. One easily sees that $\Delta u(x) > 0$ for all $x\in \Omega,$ i.e, $u$ is subharmonic on $\Omega$. In my particular, it also holds that $x'\in \partial\Omega$,
$\Delta u(x') > 0.$

Is there any sufficient condition on $f$ in order to conclude that $u$ is constant on a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}^N?$ What if we instead of $\mathbb{R}^N$ one considers a smooth closed manifold?

**EDIT:** Some additional info:
Since,
$$ 0<B(x) = \Delta u(x) + f(x)u(x),$$
by the Bochner's formula,
$$\dfrac{1}{2}\Delta|\nabla u|^2 = \langle \nabla B(x),\nabla u\rangle -\langle \nabla (fu),\nabla u\rangle + |\nabla^2 u|^2 + \mathrm{Ric}(\nabla u).$$

If one assumes that instead of $\mathbb{R}^N$ we are on a closed Riemannian manifold with positive sectional curvature, $u$ has a critical point $x^*$ (in fact, it has a maximum and a minimum). Furthermore, on this point,
$$\dfrac{1}{2}\Delta |\nabla u|^2(x^*) = |\nabla^2u| + \mathrm{Ric}(\nabla u).$$

Hence, there is an open neighborhood $U\ni x^*$ such that
$$\Delta |\nabla u|^2(x) > 0 ~\forall x\in U,$$
in particular, $|\nabla u|^2$ is subharmonic on this neighborhood.

But since 
$-fu + B = \Delta u$, if $x^*$ is a maximum point, then by possibly reducing $U$, $$\forall x\in U, \Delta u(x) < 0,$$ and hence, $$-fu(x) + B(x)< 0\forall x\in U,$$ in particular, since $u$ is negative, $$f(x) < 0~\forall x \in U \Rightarrow U\subset \Omega'. $$

Since $\nabla u (x^*) = 0$ if one shows that $|\nabla u|$ is constant on $U$, i.e, $|\nabla u|^2$ does not attaches its maximum on $\partial U$, then $|\nabla u|(x) = 0 ~\forall x\in U,$ in particular, $u$ will be constant on $U$. But note that since $\Delta |\nabla u|^2 > 0~\forall x\in U,$ $|\nabla u|^2$ cannot achieves its maximum on the interior of $U$. On the other hand, $\Delta u <0$ in $U$, hence, $u$ is superharmonic in $U$, therefore, $-u$ is subharmonic on $U$.

I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: A semi-trivial remark: if $\Omega$ is bounded and $N \geqslant 3$, then $u = -(-\Delta - f(x))^{-1} B(x)$ always exists (the inverse of $-\Delta - f(x)$ has non-negative kernel), and apparently need not be constant anywhere.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki, in fact, on $\Omega$ $u$ is never constant since $B(x) >0$, what about on $\Omega^c?$

Comment: I might have misunderstood something: you can choose $u$ and $B$ first, and then *define* $f$ using your equation, so $u$ can well happen to be constant on some set with non-empty interior. For example, take $u = -1 - \phi$ for your favourite bump function $\phi$, and $B = 1$. Then $f = (B - \Delta u) / u$ is obviously well-defined and smooth, and by choosing $\phi$ appropriately, we can require $f$ to change sign.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki, thank your for your answer. I do appreciate it, it seems nice. I will think about it, as I see, I cannot tell, would be a problem if $B$ is not constant?

Comment: Regarding non-constant $B$: this does not seem to be a problem, an arbitrary function $B$ would work as well. But this is not an answer; just a hint that any reasonable condition on $f$ (or perhaps jointly on $f$ and $B$) is likely to be complicated.